# Esconder e mostrar botão em uma DataTable com jquery

Tags: jquery, datatable

Tenho que mostrar ou esconder um botão dentro da minha DataTable conforme o retorno de uma função ajax.

Eu já consigo esconder (escondo todos por padrão) e já sei quando tenho que mostrar o botão, o problema é que não consigo mostrar o botão especifico daquela TR.

Está é minha função:

```
$JQuery(document).ready(function() {
    $JQuery(".regra").hide();
    $.post("/main/conciliacao/botao", {id:<?php echo $id ?>, processo:<?php echo $processo ?>}, function(d) {
        if (d !== "false") {
            var aux = d.split(":");
            for (i = 0; i < aux.length; i++) {
                var n = aux[i].replace(/[^\d]+/g, '');
                $("tbody>tr").each(function(index, tr) {
                    var id = tr.cells[0].innerHTML;
                    if (n == id) {
                        var botoes = tr.cells[4].innerHTML;
                        alert(botoes);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Eu já consigo acessar o que tem na cell dos botões:

```
<a class="grid" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Arrumar erros"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-list"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<a style="display: none;" class="regra" href="javascript:void(0)" title="Aplicar regra"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-book"></i></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
```

Meu problema é que não acho nada para usar o `.show()` que mostre apenas o botão daquela TR.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/filadown/e1vqqvfg/1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@SeF, você pode utilizar um segundo parametro no seletor do jQuery.
Caso você o informe, ele irá buscar apenas os objetos DOM que estão dentro do mesmo.
Então para fazer o que deseja, terá que buscar todos os objetos DOM com a classe regra dentro da `tr` atual.

```
$("tbody>tr").each(function(index, tr) {
    tr = $(tr);
    var link = $(".regra", tr);
    link.show();

    var id = tr.cells[0].innerHTML;
    if (n == id) {
        var botoes = tr.cells[4].innerHTML;
        alert(botoes);
    }
});
```